# How do I get suspend icon in Unity dash in Ubuntu 14.04 like 18.04?

Tags: unity, suspend, unity-dash

In Ubuntu 18.04 searching by 'suspend' shows a icon that results suspend the pc.

May be this feature is for gnome-extension.

Can I get this feature in 14.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this on Ubuntu 14.04 using by installing the `power-commands` package from the ["atareao-team" PPA](https://launchpad.net/~atareao/+archive/ubuntu/atareao). Then you'll find shutdown/reboot/suspend and other options by searching in the Unity dash.

[image]

To install the package, run the following commands.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install power-commands
```

Source: [article posted at maketecheasier.com](https://www.maketecheasier.com/add-session-management-options-unity-dash/)